# Отсутствует nuget.org как источник пакета

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

[image: Отсутствует nuget.org как источник пакета]

При попытке добавить источник в ручную, в "обзоре" вылазит ошибка:

```
[nuget.org] Веб-канал V2 в "https://www.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net5.0'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0" вернул непредвиденный код состояния: "404 Not Found".
Произошла ошибка при извлечении метаданных пакета для "newtonsoft.json" из источника "nuget.org".
```

[image: Ручное добавление источника]

что делать?

Comment: Возможно в Источник должно быть: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.